# Distinguish clients in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

So I would like to implement a view counter, but I'm not sure if there's a way to do it client-side only. AFAIK there is no way to use the client's IP address without a server to verify it and firebase doesn't have a support for this, how could I implement a view counter for unauthenticated users?

Obviously authenticated users are no problem since I can use the uid for them, but is there a way to distinguish unauthenticated users?

Comment: You'd use anonymous authentication for that, it identifies the users with them having to sign in. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth

Comment: I was looking at that, but as I understand the documentation (and your answer) this requires the user to do a manual login/signup. Can that be avoided somehow? Or did I totally misunderstood the docs?

Comment: You misunderstood: all that is required is that your code signs in the "user" if there is no signed in user yet. The page contains a full example. The most important code is in step 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use [Firebase anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth) for that. Using anonymous authentication identifies the users with them having to sign in.

Your application code essentially defines an identified session this way, which you can use on the back-end (or if you're using the Firebase database in your [database's security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/)) to restrict the number of votes each such session can cast.